# ¿Como agregar texto a un script de progressbarjs?

Tags: javascript, progressbar

estoy utilizando un script circular de ProgressbarJS. Dentro del círculo le añadí el porcentaje en número, basándome en otro de sus scripts. Luego busqué un script que ejecutara el script anterior una vez que el usuario hiciera scroll y pasara sobre un ID determinado. Hasta ahí todo bien, hace lo que describo, sin embargo necesito que debajo del círculo haya un texto (una palabra) y no logro como integrar esa palabra al script. Primero intenté hacerlo directamente en el HTML y sí funcionó, pero permanece visible todo el tiempo debido a que no forma parte del script que se está ocultando así que quise integrar la palabra al script del círculo progresivo. Supongo que es algo muy sencillo, intenté buscar como imprimir una palabra en el script pero no logro hacerlo. Intenté con `document.write("palabra")` y solo aparece la palabra y desaparece el círculo, también intenté con `document.getElementById('padre').insertBefore("palabra");` aunque la escribiera antes de.

Como no se Javascript se me está complicando mucho algo que supongo será muy sencillo para ustedes xc. Ojalá puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias de antemano.

https://jsfiddle.net/bth9ukq4/

```js
// progressbar.js@1.0.0 version is used
// Docs: http://progressbarjs.readthedocs.org/en/1.0.0/

var bar = new ProgressBar.Circle(container, {
  color: '#FFEA82',
  trailColor: '#eee',
  trailWidth: 1,
  duration: 1400,
  easing: 'bounce',
  strokeWidth: 6,
  from: {color: '#FFEA82', a:0},
  to: {color: '#ED6A5A', a:1},
  // Set default step function for all animate calls

                  
  step: function(state, circle) {
    circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
     var value = Math.round(circle.value() * 100);

    if (value === 0) {
      circle.setText('');
    } else {
      circle.setText(value +'%');
 
    }
       
 
  }
  
});
 
bar.text.style.fontFamily = '"Rubik", Helvetica, sans-serif';
bar.text.style.fontSize = '100%';
bar.animate(1.0);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
```

```css
#container {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/1.0.0/dist/progressbar.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.write()` escribe en el elemento o contexto donde se encuentra el *script*, nada recomendable porque no se tiene un control sobre el mismo.

`.insertBefore()` pudiera ser más apropiado si solo vas a ejecutarlo una vez, de lo contrario, debes analizar si ya se agregó el elemento cada que desees mostrar contenido.

Creo que lo más apropiado es crear un elemento HTML desde el principio, acceder por su ID (o clase) y actualizar cada que se requiera con `elemento.innerHTML = 'nuevo valor';`

```js
// progressbar.js@1.0.0 version is used
// Docs: http://progressbarjs.readthedocs.org/en/1.0.0/

// Obtener el elemento donde se mostrará el texto
let palabra = document.querySelector('#palabra');

var bar = new ProgressBar.Circle(container, {
  color: '#FFEA82',
  trailColor: '#eee',
  trailWidth: 1,
  duration: 1400,
  easing: 'bounce',
  strokeWidth: 6,
  from: {color: '#FFEA82', a:0},
  to: {color: '#ED6A5A', a:1},
  // Set default step function for all animate calls

                  
  step: function(state, circle) {
    circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
     var value = Math.round(circle.value() * 100);

    if (value === 0) {
      circle.setText('');
    } else {
      circle.setText(value +'%');
      // Actualizar contenido de elemento
      palabra.innerText = 'Valor = ' + value + '%';
    }
       
 
  }
  
});
 
bar.text.style.fontFamily = '"Rubik", Helvetica, sans-serif';
bar.text.style.fontSize = '100%';
bar.animate(1.0);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
```

```css
#container {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#palabra {
  width:200px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/1.0.0/dist/progressbar.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="palabra"></div>
```

Comment: Ya probé el funcionamiento en mi página y es exactamente lo que buscaba hacer ¡muchísimas gracias!